# How to split a string by comma without including comma inside the quotation mark in perl?

Tags: perl, split

I have this code below:

```
my $file = 'c:\test.log';
open (FILE, "<", $file) or die $!;
my @list = grep /\bAdobe\b/, <FILE>;
my $days;
foreach (@list) {
    $days = $_;
    print "$days\n";
}
```

Expected Result is:

```
"Adobe","10:10:10, 11/10/2011","Ready"
```

I want to split the result by comma with this code below:

```
my @sample = split(',', $days);
```

Expected Result is:

```
"Adobe"
"10:10:10
11/10/2011"
"Ready"
```

but it's not what I wanted to do.

I want to print the output like this:

```
"Adobe"
"10:10:10, 11/10/2011"
"Ready"
```

How could I achieve this without using/installing any module like Text::CSV?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ideally, you would use a CSV parser, see [Text::CSV](http://search.cpan.org/~makamaka/Text-CSV-1.21/lib/Text/CSV.pm). Or as long as all the fields are double quoted, then you can use a split with a slightly more complicated regex, which checks for the delimiters:

```
split /(?<="),(?=")/, $days;
```

Comment: It worked! thanks. All I need to is eliminate the quotations.

Answer (score 4):

I believe it's work for [`Text::CSV`](https://metacpan.org/module/Text%3a%3aCSV) module.
Something like this example should works:

```
use Text::CSV;

my $file = 'c:\test.log';
open (my $FILE, "<", $file) or die $!;
my $csv = Text::CSV->new;

while (my $row = $csv->getline($FILE)) {
  my @sample = @$row;
  next if $sample[0] !~ /\bAdobe\b/;
  # do whatever you want
}
```

Comment: Yes, I've already tried this one. But I am restricted not to use/install any module from cpan.

Comment: It's not mandatory to 'install', just download from cpan, extract and put "use lib 'path/to/text-csv/lib'" somewhere in head of your script.

Answer (score 2):

There's no need to install Text::CSV from CPAN (although, if you have that restriction then you really need to get that fixed) as the [Text::ParseWords](https://metacpan.org/release/Text-ParseWords/) module from the standard distribution can be used too.

Answer (score 1):

Since the string `"Adobe","10:10:10, 11/10/2011","Ready"` is valid as perl code, you can use [`eval`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/eval.html):

```
my $file = 'c:\test.log';
open my $fh, "<", $file or die $!;
for (grep /\bAdobe\b/, <FILE>) {
    my @sample = eval;
    # code here
}
```

But only do this for data you are sure is in a valid format.

Output from [Data::Dumper](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Data%3a%3aDumper):

```
$VAR1 = [
          "Adobe",
          "10:10:10, 11/10/2011",
          "Ready"
        ];
```